# How can i put more options for the user to enter in python?

Tags: python

I want to edit this code and allow the user to enter either: `Yes | No`, `Y | y`, or `N | n`!

Can somebody help me please?

```
answer = input ("Is your data correct? Please say Y or N only! : ")

if answer == "Y":
    print("Thankyou!")
else:
    print("Please re-enter your data again!")
```

Answer (score 4):

This should cover all your cases:

```
if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
```

Convert to lower case and just check the first letter. If you want to really limit the answer to variations of `y` and `yes`, you could do:

```
if answer.lower() in ("y", "yes"):
```